# Check if the second array contains the first array's element then show that

Tags: javascript, arrays

Check if the second array contains the first array's element then show that otherwise show the second array element (which is not in the first one)

```
var contacts = [{name:'muzz',no:1},{name:'muzamil',no:2},{name:'hamza',no:3}]

var recipient = ['2','4']

function check () {
   contacts.forEach(({name,no}) => {
          if(recipient.includes(no.toString())){
           console.log('exists',name)
          } 
        else {
            recipient.forEach(e =>{
                if(!recipient.includes(no.toString()) && contacts == no){
                    console.log(e);

                }
            })
       }
   })
}
```

kindly tell me what I am missing here. The else block again traverses all the elements

Comment: `contacts == no` will be always falsy as you are comparing number to the array.

Comment: I know but whats the solution to achieve my goal

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: I am expecting the  name of the contacts if they exist in the second array otherwise just shows the recipient numbers which are not included in the contacts array. i.e output should be -> muzamil , 4

Comment: @Muzamilijaz, I have posted my answer, please check:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
function resolve (a, b) {
    const map = a.reduce((acc, {no}, i) => (acc[no] = a[i], acc), {})
    return b.reduce((acc, el) => (acc.push(map[el]?.name ?? el), acc), [])
}

var contacts = [{name:'muzz',no:1},{name:'muzamil',no:2},{name:'hamza',no:3}]
var recipients = ['2','4']
const resolved = resolve(contacts, recipients)
console.log(resolved)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the *recipient* array first, then filter the object from the *contacts* array by matching the current *recipient*:

```js
var contacts = [{name:'muzz',no:1},{name:'muzamil',no:2},{name:'hamza',no:3}]

var recipient = ['2','4']

function check () {
  recipient.forEach(r => {
    var c = contacts.filter(c => c.no == r);
    if(c.length){
      console.log('exists',c[0].name)
    } 
    else {
      console.log(r);
    }
  });
}
check();
```